# Convert date initially in character type to date

Tags: r, date

There's a column with dates in my dataframe :

```
datemailing
25/04/2018
22/02/2018
22/02/2018
...
```

R considers that it's chr, so I'd like to convert it in date. 
I used :

```
attest$datemailing<-as.Date(attest$datemailing)
```

normally it works, but not this time. It converts the column in date, but displays :

```
datemailing
0025-04-20
0022-02-20
0022-02-20
```

Does anyone have an easy way to convert chr to date ?

Comment: `as.Date(x, "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: that's easy! and it works : )